# ALB request header Host shows IP instead of URL

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I would like to get the request.host header from the request which should return a URL. But ALB adds an IP address to the host header instead of a URL.

I've enabled the Preserve Host Header option on the ALB and yet I still get an IP and port.

Example Header Dump:

```
SERVER LOG:  {
  tenantName: '10.131.25.198',
  parsedUrl: URL {
    href: 'http://10.131.25.198:30495/',
    origin: 'http://10.131.25.198:30495',
    protocol: 'http:',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    host: '10.131.25.198:30495',
    hostname: '10.131.25.198',
    port: '30495',
    pathname: '/',
    search: '',
    searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
    hash: ''
  },
  host: '10.131.25.198:30495'
}
```

This is an internal ALB.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the IP was coming only when the request was a healthcheck. Normal requests had the correct host header.